# Create Ximage from (wpf) visual in memory

Tags: wpf, vb.net, printing, pdfsharp

I'm trying to convert a visual to a Ximage(to print on pdf).
Currently I'm using this:

```
 Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromFile(path.LocalPath)
```

But it requires me to save it on the harddrive
I would like to use this but I don't know how to create a image from a visual(in memory) and load it in.

```
 Dim img As XImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(myVisualAsImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the WPF build of PDFsharp, you can also use:

```
public static XImage FromBitmapSource(BitmapSource image)
```

Several classes (including BitmapImage and WriteableBitmap) are derived from BitmapSource and can also be passed here.

See also:
http://ryancdavidson.com/blog/2009/09/getting-and-using-the-pixels-of-your-visual-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks, now my pdf actually contains an image. I was using the build from nuget(the wpf build isn't available there).

Answer (score -1):

vb.net - overcome missing method FromGdiPlusImage in PDFSharp 1.5

```
Function getTiffImage(sourceImage As Image, pageNumber As Integer) As XImage
    Dim ms As MemoryStream
    Dim returnImage As XImage
    Try
        ms = New MemoryStream()
        Dim objGuid As Guid = sourceImage.FrameDimensionsList(0)
        Dim objDimension As Imaging.FrameDimension = New Imaging.FrameDimension(objGuid)
        sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, pageNumber)
        sourceImage.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
        returnImage = XImage.FromStream(ms)
    Catch ex As Exception
        returnImage = Nothing
    End Try
    Return returnImage
```

Comment: The method `FromGdiPlusImage` is still included with the GDI+ build of PDFsharp 1.5. The question is about WPF visuals, not about GDI+ images so your answer looks "off topic" to me.